# get length of json array of objects that match a specific string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I have an array of objects called friends

```
let friends = [
    {"name": "test 1", "type": "pending"}, 
    {"name": "test 2", "type": "friends"}, 
    {"name": "test 3", "type": "friends"},
    {"name": "test 4", "type": "friends"},
    {"name": "test 5", "type": "alien"}
]
```

how would I get the length of friends where pending would be excluded? I'm using this, but is there an easier way?

```
let total = friends.filter(friend=>friend.type==='friends').length + friends.filter(friend=>friend.type==='alien').length;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `filter` that array to create a new array and then get its length, just use the function `reduce` to make a simple count.

```js
let friends = [    {"name": "test 1", "type": "pending"},     {"name": "test 2", "type": "friends"},     {"name": "test 3", "type": "friends"},    {"name": "test 4", "type": "friends"},    {"name": "test 5", "type": "alien"}],
    count = friends.reduce((a, t) => a + (t.type !== 'pending'), 0);

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: No need for a conditional, `a + (t.type !== 'pending')` should do it.

Comment: @georg come on!! `:)` good advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do with single filter query with **`!=`**

**DEMO**

```js
let friends = [
    {"name": "test 1", "type": "pending"}, 
    {"name": "test 2", "type": "friends"}, 
    {"name": "test 3", "type": "friends"},
    {"name": "test 4", "type": "friends"},
    {"name": "test 5", "type": "alien"}
];

let count = friends.filter(t=>t.type !== 'pending').length;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: OP used `===` so I think your answer should use `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: @ShioT Yes updated